# How to make a custom validator work after component upload?

Tags: angular

Trying to create an custom validator for a form, which gives out an array of strings:
["First","Second"...]

Ts:

```
for: new FormControl([], this.empty)

empty(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    if (c.value.length == 0) { 
      return {"emptyMultiSelect": true}
    }
    return null;
  }
```

html

```
<cs-multiselect id = "sf_name" [options] = countries label  = "For" formControlName = for></cs-multiselect>
        <div *ngIf = "submitted && Pricelist.controls[i].controls.for.errors" class = "invalid-feedback">error</div>
```

Tried both with brackets after the empty, tried it with a nested function, doesn't work.

Comment: formControlName needs to be a string with quotes around "for". I think you may not actually be binding to your form control (thus the validator not applying).

Comment: It works fine with the rest though